# Jaxb simple question about tag wrapping

Tags: java, jaxb

When we map List we can use `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation to wrap every element in some tag. But if this Collection holds instances from different classes and we want use different tags for them, what should we do? add some annotation for each class that can be contained in this collection? what annotation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for @XmlElements which is how JAXB represents choice structures:

```
@XmlElements(value = {
        @XmlElement(name="address",
                    type=Address.class),
        @XmlElement(name="phone-number",
                    type=PhoneNumber.class),
        @XmlElement(name="note",
                    type=String.class)
})
private List<Object> contactInfo;
```

For a more detailed Example see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html

Comment: Hm. Very interesting.  If there is such stuff, why there is not easy way for inheritance?

Comment: Checkout:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html and http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html for an explanation of JAXB and inheritance.

Comment: Damn. How can I skipped you second article when I search info about? I've mapped inheritance in some very ugly way. But, after this, I will rewrite that stuff. Thanks a lot.